# How can I generate release notes automatically from JIRA using TeamCity?

Tags: build, msbuild, teamcity, jira

I use JIRA to store my my user stories and TeamCity to do my daily builds.  I am trying to automate the generation of release notes (for only completed user stories) via the TeamCity build. Have you guys done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a work around. here is the link to the steps

[How can TeamCity generate Release notes from JIRA during a build](http://ahmedgadir.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-can-teamcity-generate-release-notes.html)

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just implemented the TeamCity meta-runner which generates release notes with commits and tasks from the current TeamCity build, so you don't need to use JQL.

Give it a try.

https://github.com/olsh/teamcity-jira-release-notes/blob/master/GenerateJiraReleaseNotes.xml